# Divide count by count(*) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, alias, divide

Here is my query :

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.id IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS nb_null,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS nb_not_null
FROM
    table t
```

Is it possible to divide a field by an alias? :

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.id IS NULL THEN 1 END) / total AS nb_null,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS nb_not_null
FROM
    table t
```

It doesn't work for me in SQL Server, I'd like to know if there is any way to do this? Thanks

Comment: So this seemingly "easy" question has collected some very interesting answers and comments...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Instead of

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN t.id is null THEN 1 END)/Count(*)
```

You can use

```
AVG(CASE WHEN t.id is null THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: How interesting!

Comment: Much simpler, +1

Comment: Oh man, how did you figure this out!?  Why does 1.0 work and not 1? Tricky

Comment: Works with Laravel `\DB::raw()` (orderBy AVG of join), +1

Comment: ref the 1.0 trick. dividing int/int gives int. dividing int/numeric, numeric/int or numeric/numeric gives numeric. U may check with select sql_variant_property(1/1.0, 'basetype').

Answer (score 6):

I needed to solve a similar problem with an arbitrary number of features (not just null versus non-null), and I also wanted them converted to percentages. This may be helpful for you or someone else with a similar question:

```
WITH counts AS 
  (SELECT [feature], 
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM [your_table]
  GROUP BY [feature])
SELECT [feature], CAST(100 * num AS DOUBLE) / (SELECT SUM(num) FROM counts) 
  AS pct
FROM counts
ORDER BY pct DESC
```

Comment: You were right! Any idea how to filter so you only keep percentages > 5% (for example). Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out! 
`WITH counts AS 
  (SELECT [feature], 
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM [your_table]
  GROUP BY [feature])
SELECT [feature], CAST(100 * num AS DOUBLE) / (SELECT SUM(num) FROM counts) 
  AS pct
FROM counts
**WHERE pct > 5**
ORDER BY pct DESC`

Comment: Hi a bit new to these but where is "num" coming from ?  I don't see it called anywhere ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can not use an `alias` like that in Sql Server; you have to repeat the expression. You can (as you have already found and others have posted) use a subquery/cte/join etc to return a column with that alias and use it like that, but that is then the column/expression's name, not an alias.

```
SELECT Count(*) as total,
count(CASE WHEN t.id is null THEN 1 END)/(Count(*)+.0)  as nb_null,
COUNT(CASE WHEN t.id is not null THEN 1 END) as nb_not_null
from table t
```

Also, add `+.0` to either side of your division equation to avoid integer division (returning 0 instead of 0.dddd for percent).

Comment: Upvoting for the integer division remedy!

Comment: The "you can not" makes this a wrong answer though.

Comment: `COUNT` always returns an integer, regardless of its input. You need `1.0 * COUNT(...)` or `SUM`.

Comment: @hvd it is a very good answer, if you read the question carefully :-)

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis To the question "Is it possible to divide a field by an alias?" (a quote from the question), the answer "you can not" is incorrect and the OP has shown how it can be done. (The edited answer covers this. Now it's merely a slight disagreement on terminology, but the answer looks okay.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Good catch

Comment: @Hvd Once you have wrapped the query up as a subquery or cte or whatever, it is returning an expression with a name, so that name is no longer an alias in the scope of the outer query. So I guess it would depend on how strictly you define `alias`.

Comment: But doesn't alias have a well-defined definition?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql column_ alias
Is an alternative name to replace the column name in the query result set. For example, an alias such as Quantity, or Quantity to Date, or Qty can be specified for a column named quantity.....column_alias can be used in an ORDER BY clause. However, it cannot be used in a WHERE, GROUP BY, or HAVING clause. If the query expression is part of a DECLARE CURSOR statement, column_alias cannot be used in the FOR UPDATE clause.

Comment: @SqlZim this was a rhetoric question, that's why I have been defending your answer from the start of this discussion!

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis I know, and I appreciate that :) I just thought I'd post it here anyway since you asked.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis No, it doesn't have a well-defined definition. The documentation specifies that in `SELECT 1 AS x`, `x` is an alias, but it doesn't specify whether the first `x` in `SELECT x FROM (SELECT 1 AS x) AS y` is still a use of an alias, or whether it's now a non-alias column name. I agree with SqlZim's comment: it depends on how strictly you define "alias".

Comment: @hvd So you suggest to give the definition the benefit of the doubt, because it doesn't state explicitly that this is not an alias? Might be so, but still such interpretations cannot justify the confidence by which you declared the answer wrong... Take care!

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis Even if we can quibble over whether "alias" was the right term to use, the actual problem the OP was asking help with was avoiding repetition of the expression. The answer suggested that the repetition was unavoidable, and that's what I thought wrong. The answer now no longer makes that suggestion. I think it's okay if we don't agree on this though.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found it myself :

```
SELECT nb_null/total from(
   SELECT Count(*) as total,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN t.id is null THEN 1 END) as nb_null,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN t.id is not null THEN 1 END) as nb_not_null
   from table t
) as req
```

Comment: This would be my approach as well. By the way, dividing nb_null / total will give 0!

Comment: That's right. There are a few other ways that could work too, such as `WITH req AS (SELECT ...) SELECT nb_null/total FROM req;`.

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as:

```
select Count(*) as total,
       avg(case when t.id is null then 1.0 else 0 end) as nb_null,
       count(t.id) as nb_not_null
from table t;
```

The definition of `COUNT(<col>)` is that it counts non-NULL values; you might was well use the built-in function.

However, why a column called `id` could be `NULL` is beyond me.  It should be declared `NOT NULL`.

Comment: `t` could be an outer joined table maybe in the real query?

Comment: Nobody can mess with @Gordon ever ever. He is beyond this planet.